# Filter by many elements in a many to many relationship without using HAVING?

Tags: sql, having-clause

Is there a way to write a parametric SQL query that matches notes linked to multiple projects without using **HAVING** ?

[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e502d/6)

Say I have a "notes" table, a "projects" table and a "notes_projects" table linking these two together. I want to find the notes linked to all the project ids in the **IN** clause. Here is a version with **HAVING**:

```
SELECT notes.*, COUNT(np.project_id) AS np_count
FROM notes
INNER JOIN notes_projects AS np
  ON np.note_id = notes.id
WHERE np.project_id IN (?)
GROUP BY notes.id
HAVING np_count = 2;
```

Is there a way to not use the **HAVING** clause or is this the correct way to handle such cases ?

Comment: See [Divided We Stand: The SQL of Relational Division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) for some other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Don't join the link table because that changes the row count. Formulate the query using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM notes n
WHERE EXISTS (
 SELECT *
 FROM notes_projects AS np
 WHERE np.note_id = notes.id AND np.project_id IN (?)
)
```

(The grouping in your query was just there to fix up the problems the join caused.)

Here is a version that requires all projects to be found:

```
SELECT *
FROM notes n
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
 SELECT *
 FROM notes_projects AS np
 WHERE np.note_id = notes.id AND np.project_id NOT IN (?)
)
```

Comment: This solution does not work because it finds the notes related to *any* of the projects, not *all*.

Comment: Added the requested functionality. Hope I understood the requirement this time. If not, try playing with the code a bit. I'm quite sure you can adapt it to your needs.